# ClickOnce, Azure, and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, clickonce

I have an ASP.NET Core application published to Azure. It contains companion application published using ClickOnce.

When I look at the web server's console, I see all of the necessary ClickOnce files. And I can launch the application using `http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tools/MyApp.application` as expected.

But if I click on `http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tools/setup.exe` it fails with a 404 error.

I'm assuming that the ASP.NET application is preventing "setup.exe" from being exposed, but I don't know how to alter that configuration.

Comment: I would think that normally a .exe file can get downloaded just fine from an IIS application, however you should explicitly tell ASP.NET Core to enable serving static files. Since you're able to launch the application I'm guessing static files aren't the issue? Did you enable them in ASP.NET Core? Maybe adding .exe as a [MIME type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap) would help.

Comment: Static files are enabled. And I know this works in IIS with classic ASP.NET.

Comment: I'll try the MIME type thing tomorrow. It sounds promising.

Comment: So did you get it to work?